# how to solve Azure Storage: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format by using Azure Service BUS?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azureservicebus

What are the possible reasons for the error "Azure Storage: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format"?

My error:

Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Service request failed.

Status: 400 (The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.)

ErrorCode: InvalidHeaderValue

it is throwing below errors :

[image]

Error is happening in BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.cs belongs to Microsoft.

[image]

Comment: This looks to be related to the Functions host, which uses Azure Storage for some infrastructure and state management.    The Service Bus client library and Service Bus bindings do not make use of Storage.  It's difficult to even speculate further due to lack of context around your application, its code, what packages are in use, and where things are running when you see this exception.

Comment: When I press f5 I am getting error (2) picture. When I create an order from postman, OrderProcessor giving (1) picture.

Comment: @loki share the repro, Functions SDK version, dependencies version. The error, as Jesse pointed out, has nothing to do with ASB.

Comment: <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>